# Lombok's builder with mandatory parameters

Tags: java, builder, lombok

If I add @Builder to a class. The builder method is created.

```
Person.builder().name("john").surname("Smith").build();
```

I have a requirement where a particular field is mandatory. In this case, the name field is mandatory. Ideally, I would like to declare it like so.

```
Person.builder("john").surname("Smith").build();
```

When googling i found many alternatives like overriding the builder implementation as below:

```
@Builder
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public static PersonBuilder builder(String name) {
        return new PersonBuilder().name(name);
    }
}
```

And then use it like below:

```
Person p = Person.builder("Name").surname("Surname").build();
```

The problem with above approach is that it still provides the name() and PersonBuilder() method like below, which i don't want:

```
Person p = Person.builder("Name").surname("Surname").name("").build();
```

```
Person p = new Person.PersonBuilder().build;
```

Another approach is to add @lombok.nonnull check at name which will force to provide value for name while creating object. but it is a runtime check. it will not force me to provide value for name while creating object.

Is there any additional technique which lombok provides to achieve below:

```
 Person p = Person.builder("Name").surname("Surname").build();
```

Note: The builder() and name() should not be exposed. The only way to create Person object should be either above or below:

```
 Person p = Person.builder("Name").build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do it with lombok, see [the explanation from the library authors](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/wiki/FEATURE-IDEA:-%22Mandatory%22-fields-with-@Builder). But is it that complicated to roll this builder on your own?

```
public static class PersonBuilder {

    private final String name;
    private String surname;

    PersonBuilder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public PersonBuilder surname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
        return this;
    }

    public Person build() {
        return new Person(name, surname);
    }
        
}
```

with the same method that you already have:

```
    public static PersonBuilder builder(String name) {
        return new PersonBuilder(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the builder private.

Did you check this comment [Required arguments with a Lombok @Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885428/required-arguments-with-a-lombok-builder#comment103350941_30867286)

I am pretty sure you will find out once read the thread one more time.

P.S. If you have a class with only two field better use directly a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the thread and i found that few things were unanswered. Making the builder private solved one of the issue. but my another concern is that the `name()` method is visible and one can use it like below:
`Person.builder("Name").surname("Surname").name("").build();`
in this case the value provided in the `builder()` will be changed.

Comment: @rohit I believe you have to write own builder and not use Lombok for your specific case as it seems, fields are still public.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice:

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NonNull;

@Builder(builderMethodName = "privateBuilder")
public class Person {
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public static class PersonNameBuilder {
        public PersonBuilder name(String name) {
            return Person.privateBuilder().name(name);
        }
    }
    
    private static class PersonExtraBuilder extends PersonBuilder{
        @Deprecated
        @Override
        public PersonBuilder name(String name) {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static PersonNameBuilder builder(String name) {
        return new PersonNameBuilder();
    }

    private static PersonExtraBuilder privateBuilder(){
        return new PersonExtraBuilder();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
PersonNameBuilder nameBuilder = Person.builder();
PersonBuilder builder = nameBuilder.name("John");
Person p1 = builder.surname("Smith").build();

// Or
Person p2 = Person.builder().name("John").surname("Smith").build();

// The last `.name("")` will not work, and it will be marked as Deprecated by IDE.
Person p3 = Person.builder().name("John").surname("Smith").name("").build();
```